# Expect multiple Rails Active Jobs of the same class to be enqueued with different parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rails-activejob

I have a Rails Active Job that creates multiple other jobs of the same type with different parameters. I want to test that this job enqueues the other job with the correct parameters.

This is basically what I'm trying to achieve:

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe TriggerJob, type: :job do
  include ActiveJob::TestHelper

  after do
    clear_enqueued_jobs
  end

  it 'enqueues jobs for all model instances' do
    model1 = create(:model)
    model2 = create(:model)
    model3 = create(:model)

    expect { described_class.perform_now }
      .to(have_enqueued_job(ModelJob).with { |arg| expect(arg.id).to be == model1.id }.exactly(:once))
      .and(have_enqueued_job(ModelJob).with { |arg| expect(arg.id).to be == model2.id }.exactly(:once))
      .and(have_enqueued_job(ModelJob).with { |arg| expect(arg.id).to be == model3.id }.exactly(:once))
  end
end
```

This does not work because RSpec seems to simply match the job class type and then tries to compare the first jobs arguments with my block. Depending on the order in the queue, this fails. I'd like RSpec to match ANY of the enqueued ModelJob jobs and only fail if it can't find any match in the queue.

Additionally I'd like to test that no other ModelJob jobs exist with different parameters, but this is not really required.

Answer (score 7):

```rb
# ...
it 'schedules the job with different arguments' do
    described_class.perform_now

    expect(ModelJob).to(have_been_enqueued.at_least(:once).with(model1.id))

    expect(ModelJob).to(have_been_enqueued.at_least(:once).with(model2.id))

    expect(ModelJob).to(have_been_enqueued.at_least(:once).with(model3.id))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check `enqueued_jobs` directly. It's not as pretty, though.

```rb
  it 'enqueues jobs for all model instances' do
    model1 = create(:model)
    model2 = create(:model)
    model3 = create(:model)

    described_class.perform_now

    job_classes = enqueued_jobs.map { |enqueued_job| enqueued_job[:job] }
    expect(job_classes).to eq([ModelJob] * 3)

    job_args = enqueued_jobs.map do |enqueued_job|
      ::ActiveJob::Arguments.deserialize(enqueued_job[:args])
    end
    expect(job_args.one? { |arg| arg.id == model1.id }).to eq(true)
    expect(job_args.one? { |arg| arg.id == model2.id }).to eq(true)
    expect(job_args.one? { |arg| arg.id == model3.id }).to eq(true)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative approach which looks like this:

```
# assuming you have a user instance available
# user = create(:user)
expect(ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob).to(
  have_been_enqueued.once.with('MyMailer', 'my_email','deliver_now', args: array_including(user))
)
```

This is useful if your job accepts multiple arguments and you want to assert on one of them.